# How to improve the quality of input images and rotate images when taking pictures from the gallery?

Tags: java, android

I use the code below to get an image from the gallery and capture an image from the camera. But I don't know how my image is degraded. As for taking pictures from the gallery, it is rotated 90 degrees horizontally (I use a samsung phone to take pictures, with my other phone, it's completely normal without rotation)

`

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //Open Camera
            if (requestCode == 2) {
                Bitmap imgCam = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                int dimension = Math.min(imgCam.getWidth(), imgCam.getHeight());
                imgCam = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(imgCam, dimension, dimension);

                cropBitmap = Utils.processBitmap(imgCam, TF_OD_API_INPUT_SIZE);
                imgHinh.setImageBitmap(imgCam);

                loading = new ProgressDialog(this);
                loading.show();
                initBox();
                imgCam = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imgCam, imgSize, imgSize, true);

                Bitmap finalImgCam = imgCam;
                new CountDownTimer(2000,1000) {
                    public void onFinish() {
                        classifyImage(finalImgCam);
                        loading.dismiss();
                    }

                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                    }
                }.start();
            //Open Gallery
            } else if (requestCode == 3) {
                Uri dat = data.getData();
                Bitmap imgChoose = null;
                try {
                    imgChoose = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), dat);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                cropBitmap = Utils.processBitmap(imgChoose, TF_OD_API_INPUT_SIZE);
//                imgHinh.setImageBitmap(imgChoose);
                loading = new ProgressDialog(this);
                loading.show();
                initBox();
                int dimension = Math.min(imgChoose.getWidth(), imgChoose.getHeight());
                imgChoose = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(imgChoose, dimension, dimension);
                imgChoose = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imgChoose, imgSize, imgSize, true);
                imgHinh.setImageBitmap(imgChoose);
                Bitmap finalImgChoose = imgChoose;
                new CountDownTimer(2000,1000) {
                    public void onFinish() {
                        classifyImage(finalImgChoose);
                        loading.dismiss();
                    }

                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                    }
                }.start();
            }
        }
```

`

I don't know how to fix that. Thank you for helping me

Comment: In every picture file taken by the camera the orientation is marked. So first read orientation value from the file. Then rotate accordingly.

Comment: Further its pretty unclear why you wanna have a bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it might be helpful...

```
final int maxSize = 960;
int outWidth;
int outHeight;
int inWidth = myBitmap.getWidth();
int inHeight = myBitmap.getHeight();
if(inWidth > inHeight){
    outWidth = maxSize;
    outHeight = (inHeight * maxSize) / inWidth; 
} else {
    outHeight = maxSize;
    outWidth = (inWidth * maxSize) / inHeight; 
}

Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, outWidth, outHeight, false);

//Todo Rotate image
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate(90);

Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(resizedBitmap, 0, 0, resizedBitmap.getWidth(), resizedBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

Comment: I try your way but it can't rotate the picture

Comment: did you checked the rotatedBitmap set on ImageView?, it should be working in such scenario.

Comment: i follow you but it rotates all the images not only the one taken from samsung, i try your if condition but it doesnt work it crashes the app

Comment: when it happen when you take image form camera or from choose file form gallery?

Comment: If you have crashes then tell us which exception that you did not catch killed your app. Look in the LogCat.

Comment: error is "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: y + height must be <= bitmap.height()"

Comment: I fixed it, so how can I improve the input image quality according to my code?